# Efficient way to select a nested child nodes with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this html structure:

```
<div id="title" class="span7">
    <span id="details" class="detail pull-right">
        <a class="detailShow" href="#">More details</a>
    </span>
    <p>My text example</p>
</div>

<div class="span9 hide" style="display: block;">
    <div class="row topRow">
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="detailInfo">
                <p>Informazioni aggiuntices</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to select the .detailInfo div, starting from the first unique id I have on the div "title".

I have this code:

```
$("#title").next(".span9");
```

No idea of how go ahead...

What is the best way to select the detailInfo div?

Comment: sorry it should be "unique"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `$('.detailInfo')` select based on class.

Or more completely:

```
$("#title").next(".span9").find('.detailInfo')
```

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways to select the div, and I think the most efficient ways can be as below:

- Use *ancestor descendant* selector:

`$('#title+div .detailInfo')`

- Use the 2nd *context* parameter:

`$('.detailInfo', '#title+div')`

EDIT: Didn't notice that *div#title* is not the ancestor of the *div.detailInfo*

Comment: Updated since I did not notice that _div#title_ is not the ancestor of _div.detailInfo_.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.detailInfo')` you can select directly

```
$("#title").next(".span9").find('.detailInfo')
```

Comment: I have a lot of div with detailInfo class, I need to select it starting from the first univoque id I find on page